# Redux display error messages from Nodejs backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, error-handling, redux

I want to display the error messages I am receiving from my backend in an alert, whenever my login failes:

[image]

My login-button triggers this function from my user.actions:

```
function login(username, password) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(request({ username }));

        userService.login(username, password)
            .then(
                user => {
                    dispatch(success(user));
                    history.goBack();
                },
                error => {
                    dispatch(failure(error.toString()));
                    dispatch(alertActions.error(error.toString()));
                }
            );
    };

    function request(user) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_REQUEST, user } }
    function success(user) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS, user } }
    function failure(error) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_FAILURE, error } }
}
```

My alert.reducer looks as following:

```
  import { alertConstants } from '../_constants';

export function alert(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case alertConstants.SUCCESS:
      return {
        type: 'alert-success',
        message: action.message
      };
    case alertConstants.ERROR:
      return {
        type: 'alert-danger',
        message: action.message
      };
    case alertConstants.CLEAR:
      return {};
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

In my App.js I receive this state with mapStateToProps:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { alert } = state;
    return {
        alert
    };
}
```

After that, I want to display an alert with the alert message:

```
  {alert.message &&
                          alert(alert.message)
                        }
```

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your action/reducer code looks ok, I think maybe it is a conflict with the props name and the native alert function.
Have you tried to change the props names? Something like:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { alert } = state;
  return {
    alertState: alert
  };
}
```

and

```
{ alertState.message && alert(alertState.message) }
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you! Crazy, that it was just this little tweak... :D